# Kotlin ktor UDP server + docker issue

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, udp, ktor

I have Ktor-based ultra-simple udp server:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val server = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO))
                                  .udp()
                                  .bind(InetSocketAddress("localhost",9090))
    while (true) {
        println(server.incoming.receive().packet.readText())
    }
}
```

And I don't have problems with it on host/my-pc, but it just not working on docker. It's running, but it don`t receive UDP-packets.

That's my Dockerfile:

> FROM phusion/baseimage
>
> MAINTAINER cayzerok@gmail.com
>
> EXPOSE 9090/udp
>
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-jre-headless
>
> VOLUME /data
>
> COPY *.jar /app/server.jar
>
> RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
>
> CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/server.jar"]

And that's my "docker run" command:

> docker run -p 9090:9090/udp cayzerok/sample

What am I doing wrong? Reason must be in the server, I tested a client with docker-udp-listener.

Thanks for attention!

Comment: Try listening to 0.0.0.0 (any interface) instead of localhost.